# Google place service image returns 403 forbidden after a while

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been working on a tour service project. And I'm using google map place service to get photos of locations. I'm using following `javascript` code snippet to get a location's photo url:

```
engineMap.map.addListener('click', function (event) {
    var dataLatLng = [
        event.latLng.lat(),
        event.latLng.lng(),
        engineMap.map.getZoom()
    ];
    TourController.selected_geolocation = {
        map_lat: dataLatLng[0],
        map_lng: dataLatLng[1]
    };
    engineMap.clearMarkers();
    new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({
        'latLng': event.latLng
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var result = results[1] ? results[1] : (result[0] ? result[0] : false);
        if (result) {
            var place_id = result.place_id;
            var request = {
                placeId: place_id,
                fields: ['name', 'formatted_address', 'place_id', 'geometry', 'photos']
            };
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(engineMap.map);
            service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    var dataLatLng = [
                        TourController.selected_geolocation.map_lat,
                        TourController.selected_geolocation.map_lng,
                        engineMap.map.getZoom()
                    ];
                    engineMap.clearMarkers();
                    engineMap.addMarker(dataLatLng, {
                        title: place.name,
                        label: place.name
                    });
                    if (place.photos && place.photos.length) {

                 // ************* where i get photo url from google place service *********

                        var url = place.photos[0].getUrl({
                            maxWidth:1920,
                            maxHeight: 1080
                        }); 

                 // ************************************************************************

     // ... rest omitted ...
});
```

Returned url is like:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PhotoService.GetPhoto?1sCmRaAAAAvQxs3fvvZepgPXtVhiHOZrVNPEZq--SLJwkgxzoHlF7bLksuic5aX1a0YfaCXGKQh7c2f4un5n_wfFxYKzWVsyUzpsJy1G1BKfgvyQSDQP5QTkMkc8IA7ShFJ8KLWclZEhA05ZJUmSDqQw2n5RtCRArkGhRS-fI0dyWin4P4ME0DSIgysKIZyg&3u2048&5m1&2e1&callback=none&key=MY_GOOGLE_MAP_KEY&token=SOME_TOKEN
```

And I persist this url to a database for later shows. At first, it works well but after a while, the photo changes to a disabled image. Following the above image url returns 403 error, too. And database persistence became meaningless. I think accessing images by `javascript` (the above link shows Google uses `javascript` to determine the image url) is somewhat session-based. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Have you tried saving the place_id in your database?  If I recall correctly, that is the only thing you are allowed to persist in your database long term.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll be thinkin' about it. But there are more than one photos for each location and I want to save which photo to show.

Comment: Your use case does not appear to be compliant with Google's ToS, please see https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies#pre-fetching,-caching,-or-storage-of-content and discuss this further with your legal counsel.

Answer (score 0):

The Google API does not allow storing the photo URL. You need to store the place_id and then retrieve the photo (just as any other place data) each time you want to display it.

Comment: Maybe downloading pictures from google api and storing them would be a better solution here...

Comment: Downloading could be a solution. But I think it violates Google‘s terms and it could also leave you with outdated photos.